# SQL Server 2016 - number range in field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, range, sql-server-2016

I'm creating a database in SQL Server 2016, I'm trying to figure out how I can put a range of numbers into a column.

For example -

- Street Numbers - 1000-2999
- Street Name - Dixie Hwy
- Map Code - 205B

I would like to search "1344 Dixie Hwy" and have it return map code 205B, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to do the Street Numbers column.

Answer (score 0):

I think about the best you can do is to have a `range_start` and a `range_end`, then use a `BETWEEN` clause in the query.  So for your example:

```
Street_Number_Start - 1000
Street_Number_End - 2999
Street_Name - Dixie Hwy
Map_Code - 205B
```

and

```
select map_code
  from my_table
 where 1134 between street_number_start and street_number_end
   and street_name = 'Dixie Hwy'
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking. This is brand new to me so I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way before I entered all of these. There will be a few thousand rows that I will have to manually enter.

Comment: Well, fwiw if you think of a better way later you can use a query to migrate your data to a new structure.  But I did double-check and I don't see a type that would really support a numeric range as a single value.  I think you'd have to store it as a string, and then use a really messy expression to interpret it.  By keeping it simple as suggested here, you can more easily take advantage of indexes etc. if need be.  So that's why I'd go this way if it were me